# Continuous trigger using Red Pitaya & SCPI

Tags: redpitaya

Using SCPI, I'm trying to develop a code to count the number of times the trigger goes on using a Red Pitaya. Previously, I've done the same with an oscilloscope, using this code:

```
os.write(file, "ACQ:TYPE NORM")  
os.write(file, ":TRIG:MODE EDGE")
os.write(file, ":TRIG:EDGE:SOURCE CHAN1")
os.write(file, ":TRIG:EDGE:SLOP NEG")
os.write(file, ":TRIGger:EDGE:SWEep NORM")
os.write(file, ":TRIG:EDGE:LEVel-1")
os.write(file, ":COUNter:ENABle ON")
os.write(file, ":RUN")

os.write(file, ":COUNter:VALue?")
```

When I want to adapt the same piece of code to Red Pitaya, it just doesn't work. According to the documentation, there are certain SCPI commands that are supported, and the 'COUNter' command is not on the list. If so, how can I counter number of triggers using Red Pitaya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`COUNter` commands is not supported.

All commands are listed in the [scpi server sources](https://github.com/RedPitaya/RedPitaya/blob/master/scpi-server/src/scpi-commands.c#L96-L204).

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sanpi. Going through that list I don't see any equivalent for counting, am I right? Any ideas on how to implement a counter using RP?

Comment: I don't found equivalent command. I didn’t find either insteresting function in the [API](https://github.com/RedPitaya/RedPitaya/blob/master/api/include/redpitaya/rp.h).